# How do I add a delay between SendInput commands in AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, sendinput

I have an AutoHotkey script using [`SendInput`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) which sends [`MouseClick`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm) commands too quickly for my program to handle. My script will send a MouseClick to focus an input field, then start typing before the field finishes focusing.

I've tried using [`SetKeyDelay`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm#Remarks) to make my script run a bit slower, but this doesn't work with `SendInput`.

> **Note**: SetKeyDelay is not obeyed by SendInput; there is no delay between keystrokes in that mode. This same is true for Send when SendMode Input is in effect.
>   <sub>[Documentation for SetKeyDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm#Remarks)</sub>

My current workaround is to use sleep commands after each input, but this is less than ideal.

```
SendMode Input
F1::
  MouseClick, left, 61, 50         ; select title field
  sleep 100                        ; artificial delay to prevent misfocused inputs

  SendInput %user_input%{Enter}    ; enter job title
  sleep 100                        ; artificial delay

  MouseClick, left, 67, 408        ; select job
  sleep 100                        ; artificial delay
Return
```

Ideally I would like a more elegant solution for adding a delay between each SendInput command without manually using a sleep command each time.

**How can I add a delay between SendInput commands in AutoHotkey without repeatedly using sleep?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [SendPlay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendPlayDetail) instead of [SendInput](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail).

**This sends text and mouse clicks with a 100ms delay following each click**

```
user_input := "hello world"
SetMouseDelay 100, Play
SendPlay {Click 61,50}%user_input%{enter}{click 67,408}
```

---

From the [documentation for SendPlay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendPlayDetail).

> ## [SendPlay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendPlayDetail)
>
> **Note**: SendPlay may have no effect at all if UAC is enabled, even if the script is running as an administrator. For more information, refer to the [FAQ](https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#uac).
>
> Like [SendInput](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail), SendPlay's keystrokes do not get interspersed with keystrokes typed by the user. Thus, if the user happens to type something during a SendPlay, those keystrokes are postponed until afterward.
>
> Although SendPlay is considerably slower than SendInput, it is usually faster than the traditional [SendEvent](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendEvent) mode (even when [KeyDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm) is -1).
>
> SendPlay does not use the standard settings of SetKeyDelay and SetMouseDelay. Instead, it defaults to no delay at all, which can be changed as shown in the following examples:
>
> ```
> SetKeyDelay, 0, 10, Play  ; Note that both 0 and -1 are the same in SendPlay mode.
> SetMouseDelay, 10, Play
> ```

Comment: My understanding is that SendInput doesn't try to coordinate keyboard and mouse events or delays so it can utilize fast operating system calls that don't have such support.